# Addition of two NSDate in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two NSDates with this format : "H.m.s" and I want to do an addition of this two dates to compare the result with my current time on my phone.
I have all the information as you can see bellow :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"H:m:s"];
    NSDate *start = [dateFormat dateFromString:NextTVS.startTime];
    NSDate *duration = [dateFormat dateFromString:NextTVS.duration];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:date];
```

However I don't know how to add start and duration.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the result if you add two dates?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `dateByAddingComponents` method of the `NSCalendar` class like so:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:date];
NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: date options:0];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's ok now :)

Comment: no worries, did that work or did you find a different solution?

Comment: @Guillaume.M "it's ok now" is not helping our community. You should mark it as accepted to show that you got what you asked for.

Comment: @Desdenova I did it too, don't worry